# Strongswan Error: no config named 'foo'

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan, ikev2, point-to-site-vpn

On Ubuntu 20.04, I am trying to establish a VPN tunnel to a IKEv2/Ipsec VPN site using Strongswan.

However, even though I have the file `/etc/ipsec.conf` as shown

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no

conn foo
    left= ...
    right= ...
    ...
```

when I run `sudo ipsec up foo`, I get the error

> no config named 'foo'

I have tried the follow commands before running `ipsec up foo`, but the error persists.

```
sudo ipsec update
sudo ipsec reload 
sudo ipsec restart
```

Strongswan U5.8.2/K5.4.0-60-generic was installed using

```
sudo apt-get install strongswan libcharon-extra-plugins -y
```

What seems to be preventing the `foo` connection from being detected?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured `auto` in your conn section (the default value is `ignore`)?

Comment: @ecdsa Works after setting to `auto`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections defined in [ipsec.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Connsection) are only loaded if `auto` is configured to anything but the default value, which is `ignore`.

A connection may simply be loaded (`add`) without starting it (e.g. as responder for roadwarriors), automatically started (`start`), or trap policies (based on `left|rightsubnet`) can be loaded into the IPsec stack/kernel (`route`) so matching traffic triggers the tunnel automatically.